# C# Stop Thread using button after thread finished current function loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Windows form application which uses a start button to perform an infinite loop. I have a stop button which I am attempting to use to stop the infinite loop after the loop has completed a cycle.

I have attempted to use thread.Interrupt which doesn't allow the loop to finish.

I have also used thread.abort which obviously doesn't allow the loop to finish.

I have also attempted to do this by having the stop button update a global variable which the while loop inside my thread is reliant on but the global variable does not update inside the thread.

main class code

```
startbutton()
{
  handle = getHandle();
  Loopclass.loopclass loop = new Loopclass.loopclass(handle);
  thread = new Thread(()=>loop.run());
  thread.Start();
}

stopbutton()
{
  handle = getHandle();
  Loopclass.loopclass loop = new Loopclass.loopclass(handle);
  loop.setCh();
}
```

Loop Class code

```
//_ch is a global string variable
Run()
{
  while(_ch != "X")
  {
    //do stuff
    string x = "";
    _ch = getCh(x);
  }
}

setCh()
{
  _ch = "X";
}
  
getCh(string x)
{
  x = "X";
  return x;
}
```

Comment: I'd try using CancellationToken: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: There is nothing like a global variable. You need to create a variable with the correct scope that can be seen by all users of that variable. Then the idea mentioned by you should work.

Comment: CancellationToken is the elaborate tool to stop a thread.
But a shared boolean "variable", usually a field, that is accessed and updated thread-safe should basically also to the trick, though it's way of handwork ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Task and CancellationToken:

```
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
startbutton()
{
  handle = getHandle();
  Loopclass.loopclass loop = new Loopclass.loopclass(handle);
  tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var task = Task.Run(() => loop.Run(tokenSource.Token));
}

stopbutton()
{
   tokenSource.Cancel();
   
  //handle = getHandle();
  //Loopclass.loopclass loop = new Loopclass.loopclass(handle);
  //loop.setCh();
}

Run(CancellationToken token)
{
  while(!token.IsCancellationRequested && _ch != "X")
  {
    //do stuff
    string x = "";
    _ch = getCh(x);
  }
}

setCh()
{
  _ch = "X";
}
  
getCh(string x)
{
  x = "X";
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that works but I have removed _ch !="X" from the loop and the Settter and getter